# Django render dict to html page

Tags: python, html, django

I having a dictionary

```
a = {'name': u'45445454',
     'tracks': [{'A_TITLE': u'abb',
             'IS': u'144',
             'PN': u'3',
             'T_TITLE': u'123'},
            {'A_TITLE': u'abb',
             'IS': u'45454454',
             'PN': u'3',
             'T_TITLE': u'225'},
            {'A_TITLE': u'ggg',
             'IS': u'232',
             'PN': u'000',
             'T_TITLE': u'555'}]}
```

I want to redner this dict to my html page.

my html code is not working.

```
<table>
<tr>
{% for e in tracks %}
<td> e['IS']</td>
<td> e['PN']</td>
....
.,..
 {% endfor %}
<tr>
</table>
```

The above code throws an error.

I have changed this to

```
<table>

{% for e in tracks %}
<tr> <td> Title </td> <td> {{ e.A_TITLE }}  -  PN {{ e.PN }}</td>
<tr> <td> tc </td><td> {{e.T_TITLE }} - ISRC {{e.IS }} </td></tr>
   {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Now it is working good , And you see the dict the A_Title and PN key are dependent.

I want this to be render in html page like.

```
<tr> <td> abb - 3 </td>
     <td> 123 - 144</td>
     <td> 225 - 45454454</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td> ggg - 000</td>
     <td> 555 - 232</td>

</tr>
```

or else in this format

```
<tr> <td> abb - 3 </td></tr>
<tr>         <td> 123 - 144</td>
         <td> 225 - 45454454</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td> ggg - 000</td></tr>
<tr>         <td> 555 - 232</td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: use `{{ e.IS }} ` instead `e['IS']`

Comment: May first rummage in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#variables before you move on with templates to understand the basic ideas.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Kindly see my edit and give me the solution

Comment: @AKyhoo move your `<tr>` tags inside loop, Btw, your closing `<tr>` tag is incorrect

Comment: Yes, Please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `e.IS` in Django templates

Comment: actually `{{   }}` to render it as @che

Answer (score 2):

Django templates do not use Python, but are a special language, where constructs like `e['IS']` do not work. For this particular instance, use simply `{{e.IS}}` to substitute value of the field.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/ for complete docs of the language.

Comment: for OP:   additionally if you have list or tuple in context then you would to like `{{ L.0 }}`,  `{{ L.1 }}` but *not* `{{ L[0] }}`, `{{ L[1] }}`  (here `L`is a list)

Answer (score 0):

Use following inside `loop`

```
<td>{{ e.IS }}</td>
<td>{{ e.PN }}</td>
```